# Pug & Django: reverse URL + variable inline?

Tags: python, django, pug, pyjade

Desired output:

> You're currently [following xx artists](http://example.com/artists)

Assuming I'm using Pug in a Django template, how would I achieve that if I don't want to hardcode the URL (which I have named as `artists` in my URL), and if the artist count is also a variable?

I can do this:

```
p You're currently following #{user_artists_count} artists
```

but how can I make the last part a link to a Django URL with the name `artists`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below syntax to use the `{% url %}` django tag in pug templates.

(I put it here for reference, had been searching the last few hours for it.)

```
p You're currently 
    - url 'artists' as the_url
    a(href=the_url) following #{user_artists_count} artists
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url